# Best GTK for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gtk

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. I tried to install VMware on Ubuntu 16.04 and I also installed some other GTK versions.

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd 3.18.9-1ubun amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface lib
ii  libgtk2.0-0:am 2.24.30-1ubu amd64        GTK+ graphical user interface lib
ii  libgtk2.0-0:i3 2.24.30-1ubu i386         GTK+ graphical user interface lib
```

These are my laptop specs (Asus X751L):

```
description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5500U CPU @ 2.40GHz
          capabilities: x86-64
```

How can I restore to the default GTK version? Or which one is the best to keep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTK2 and GTK3 can be installed independently.
There are apps those require GTK2 and those require GTK3.
So you may want to keep both of those.

You have a 64-bit OS.
The `amd64` packages are needed for 64-bit applications.
The `i386` packages are need for 32-bit applications.
If you don't have any 32-bit applications installed, you may safely uninstall the `i386` version.
Although there is no harm in keeping all of those.

I am assuming that you have not installed an unsupported version of GTK using PPA's.
If you installed them from official repos, everything is fine.